# How to skip repeated records?

Tags: oracle, shell, sql-loader

I'm working on an SQL*Loader script to upload huge amounts of data to a table.

The script works in the following way:
It connects to an FTP server and mirrors a directory to get all new files that have been generated, it then takes all the CSV files and saves them into a single one and then uploads the data from within this bigger CSV file.

Basically, I'm looking for a way in which SQL*Loader doesn't even try to insert a record if the first to records already exist in the table.

The thing is, the table will hold up to 10 million records, and sometimes these files will wrongfully download when they shouldn't, which will mean that some records will repeat.

I've placed unique keys on the two fields that required it.

I tried changing the max errors to the number of rows that the script will try inserting but I noticed that doing this and letting them return the Constraint Violation error works much slower than when there are no repeated records, and it will create a really big log file.

Is there a way, inside the SQL*Loader control file, to place a condition (on two fields, as either of those can repeat but not both at the same time)?

Or what do you think could help me speed up this process?

Bonus question: Is it better if I have let's say 10 CSV files, to send each one to SQL*Loader or to make a single file containing the data from those 10?

Comment: Please clarify if it is the problem with getting the same CSV file several times, or with data that can be duplicate in different CSV files.

Comment: @Gnudiff I've edited to reflect it. I don't mind the CSV file being repeated because it will eventually happen, I want the script to ignore the rows that already exist in the table.

Comment: Allright. I started writing answer based on the idea that the problem was duplicate rows in CSV (sort & uniq would help with that), but if you need to check against the actual SQL table, then it appears you will have to do it within SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per solllodolllo answer, import records to temp table, but then

```
DELETE FROM  temptable WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM yourtable)?
```

After that you can INSERT temptable into yourtable.

This of course, depends on the way your rows can differ each from other. Possibly would be good to indicate that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent SQL Loader from inserting a record if it already exists in the table, you could use a condition statement that would make SQL Loader skip the record unless it meets your necessary conditions. For example:

```
LOAD DATA
 INFILE 'YourData.dat'
 BADFILE 'YourBadData.bad'
APPEND INTO TABLE YourTable
WHEN (Condition 1 = TRUE) AND (Condition 2 = FALSE)
{
...
```

To speed up the initial load process, you could insert all of the records into a temporary table, then use a select statement to insert all of the distinct rows into a permanent table.

```
INSERT INTO YourTable
SELECT DISTINCT [fields]
FROM tempYourTable
```

Comment: In this particular script, it's highly unlikely (practically impossible) that a same operation will have repeated records within the fetched CSV files. The thing is some of those records will be already saved into the table. I need SQL*Loader to skip these records. And your query if I'm reading correctly, will simply return all the values that are not repeated in the temp table (all of them, in my case).

Comment: In that case, you could add another step where you delete all of the existing records from the temp table, then do the insert. The steps would then be: 1. Insert records into a temp table. 2. Delete from temp table when the record exists in the permanent table. 3. Insert into permanent table from temp table.